# What happens if Host OS of MDADM md0 crashes

Tags: mdadm

So I am debating getting software RAID. But I am trying to reduce the single point of failure problem. I don't think hardware raid is an option as I can't afford a high-end adapter, and I think I like the idea of software raid better.

Anyway,

If I build a Ubuntu Server with mdadm md0 with 4x5TB drives in raid5/ext4 and lets say an **update crashed Ubuntu Server and is unrecoverable** (IE: need to reinstall OS), **would the data be recoverable?** Would it be as **simple as just "rebuilding the md0" and/or is there a current configuration stored on the HD(s) that I could load?**

To clarify, I am assuming no hard drive failure, its as if I took them out of a running server and to another computer and tried to recover the data.

And would it be different with raid10?

Comment: off topic sorda but, can I create raid5 with a drive with data on it? (2 out of 4 disks will have large amounts of data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the data would be recoverable. In fact, better so than with hardware raid, since there the on-disk format is proprietary to the raid controller and usually undocumented, which means that if the controller fails, you'll probably lose data.

You cannot create a raid array without wiping the disks in the process. However, it *is* possible to create the array in so-called *degraded mode*, where the redundant disks are added in later. If you do that, you could copy the data onto the array from the individual disks, and only then add them to the array to create redundancy.

Comment: Have you ever done this? Or just theoretical knowldge, not that I don't believe you, this is why I am leaning towards software raid. Just doing some learning before spending :)

Comment: If you have, was it hard?

Comment: What, recover or the degraded mode thing? Not sure about the latter, but the former, sure.

Comment: No no, I meant recover an Md0/Mdadm >> Was it hard? Did it take 20+ hours

Comment: I have read about degraded, just wasn't sure if that was the only option

Comment: 2 seconds, actually (plus 10 minutes reading the documentation ;-)

Comment: I am going thru a 2 or 3 day data recovery and I think you just sold me on mdadm. Off to best buy for a few 5tb disks :)

Comment: So my thought is to create md0 inside an esxi guest and export it via nfs, i just started a thread looking for opinions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645572/esxi-mapped-raw-lun-to-esxi-ubuntu-guest-creating-md0-and-exporting-over-nfs-ba) , if you have an opinion let me know!